# Position command line under current window?

Tags: command-line, split

Sometimes I work with a vertically split window and I was thinking it would be cool if when I enter the command line with `:`, `/`, etc., the command I type would appear below the current window instead of at the far left of the whole vim layout. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

No. The position of the command-line can't be changed.

Comment: Kinda jealous this short answer got 5 votes (1 of them mine).

Comment: It was shorter in my head.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled to find an easy way to change the command line, but now I see there is this plugin that intends to make it possible to change the location of the command line and the output of the command line: https://github.com/folke/noice.nvim